# bash, set variable from script to memory

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I need "set" variable from script to memory (global) and read it again in second run of this script with defined last state of this variable.

Script.

```
echo $count
let "count=count+1"
export $count
echo $count
```

This shows me `1` when I run this script again. I need `1`, and in the case I run the script again, I need `2`, in case of third run `3`, etc.

I thought `export` do this, but it is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `export` shell builtin only exports variables (and their values) to *child processes* of the current shell.

AFAIK you'd need to use some kind of state file to store a value between invocations. You can locate the file on a RAM-based filesystem such as `/var/run` if you want the value to be stored "to memory".

See for example:

- [Is it possible to have bash variables persist between runs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211032/is-it-possible-to-have-bash-variables-persist-between-runs/211045)
- [Variable in Bash Script that keeps it value from the last time running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904980/variable-in-bash-script-that-keeps-it-value-from-the-last-time-running)

Comment: Probably not applicable for a script run as normal user. You could use /tmp or /var/tmp, though. You won't notice the disk overhead (/tmp is not a memory based file system).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I tested these examples, but it is not what exactly I need. At the end, I did via storing to file, at the end, linux is based on files. ;)